# Why heatmap.2 in R failed to read the numeric data frame?

Tags: r, plot, heatmap, gplots

I have the following data

```
GOBPID  Term    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
GO:0001659  temperature_homeostasis 3.49690559977475    0   0   0   0
GO:0001660  fever_generation    3.22606939096511    0   0   0   0
```

which I tried to read with heatmap.2 function:

```
library("gplots")
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1486837/plain/",header=TRUE)
dat   <- dat[,!names(dat) %in% c("GOBPID")];
dat2 <- dat[,-1]
rownames(dat2)<-dat[,1]
heatmap.2(dat2,symm=FALSE,trace="none");
```

In my understanding it should read the data.frame correctly. 
But why it failed?

```
Error in heatmap.2(dat, symm = FALSE, trace = "none") : 
  `x' must be a numeric matrix
```

**Update:** 
I find it strange because this work,

```
library("gplots")
round(Ca <- cor(attitude), 2)
heatmap.2(Ca, symm = FALSE, margins = c(6,6))
```

The structure of `Ca` is the same with my `dat2`, no?

Comment: There are two problems - first column of dat still contains characters and it is dataframe but matrix is needed. Try heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat[,-1]),symm=FALSE,trace="none")

Comment: @DidzisElferts: Thanks. But I want the "term" as the description. See my updated example where the 'characters' column works.

Comment: dat2 is data frame but Ca is matrix. Error message say that x MUST be a numeric matrix!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function `heatmap.2()` expects that x will be numeric matrix. So you need to convert your data frame `dat2` to matrix with function `as.matrix()`.

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat2),symm=FALSE,trace="none")
```

[image]